# Android native keyboard open(but the text written in white color in lenovo tab2 model) using unity3D for android Application

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, keyboard, native

This is screen shot in which the whole text is highlighted by selecting but I want this text in color black when I open the keyboard from my unity Application.[check Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkXah.png)